# unable to start up the emulator

Tags: java, android, error-handling

i can't get my emulator to start and i don't know what is the problem i try to delete it and create new one but the error still the same

this is the error that i got in the console box

[2012-09-20 22:56:55 - SDK Manager] AVD 'GPSTest' deleted with errors. See errors above.
[2012-09-20 22:57:23 - SDK Manager] Deleting file C:\Users\GGE.android\avd\maptest.ini
[2012-09-20 22:57:23 - SDK Manager] Deleting folder C:\Users\GGE.android\avd\maptest.avd
[2012-09-20 22:57:23 - SDK Manager] AVD 'maptest' deleted.
[2012-09-20 22:57:44 - MyAndroidApp1] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-09-20 22:57:44 - MyAndroidApp1] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-09-20 22:59:02 - MyAndroidApp1] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.mkyong.android.MainActivity activity launch'!

any help ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, look up the logcat, especially at the warnings (maybe you have problems with Manifest file, I've had such experience).

Then, try this. Type the following in CMD:

```
 adb kill-server
 adb start-server
```

Comment: the strange thing that the process it never show anything  in the logcat  but i will try to kill the server maybe this will work